# cell2table truncates double values to int if a cell contains int

Tags: matlab

For example, my cell contains 2 double values and one int64 value.

```
>> cell2table({1.4;int64(4);3.2})

ans = 

    Var1
    ____

    1   
    4   
    3
```

But after the conversion, they are not converted into int. Is this expected?

Comment: Did you mean to ask whether after running cell2table the doubles *are* converted to ints? Because all the ans values are ints which seems to contradict your question.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "After the conversion"? Did you convert the table to something else?

Running these lines tells me that the numbers in that table are actually int64.

```
>> A = cell2table({1.4;int64(4);3.2})

A = 

    Var1
    ____

    1   
    4   
    3   

>> class(A.Var1)

ans =

int64

>> class(A.Var1(1))

ans =

int64

>> class(A.Var1(2))

ans =

int64

>> class(A.Var1(3))

ans =

int64
```

---

edit: `cell2table` does the conversion. Proof:

```
>> tt = {1.4;int64(4);3.2}

tt = 

    [1.4000]
    [     4]
    [3.2000]


>> class(tt{1})

ans =

double

>> class(tt{2})

ans =

int64

>> class(tt{3})

ans =

double
```

In the cell array the data type is still `double`.

Comment: In the argument of cell2table, 1.4 and 3.2 are still double. Does cell2table convert them into int64?

Comment: Is this the expected behavior of cell2table? I had thought it would not do any implicit conversion. For example, cell2table({1;'a';4}) does not convert any double or strings to other data type. Why are the double values converted to int64 if there is an int64 value.